# How to write code to connect a hardware device to Android mobile using USB cable in XAMARIN

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, cross-platform, usb-otg

My organization build **ARM chip** based hardware devices. I am trying to connect those devices via USB OTG to Android devices (Phones, tablet).

I want to do it in C#.Net using XAMARIN. I found some examples in Java Android, but nothing in .Net language.

Comment: Can you share the demo in Java

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Android.Hardware.Usb Namespace](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.Hardware.Usb/) of xamarin:

> Use [UsbManager](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Hardware.Usb.UsbManager/) to access the state of USB and to communicate with connected hardware peripherals. Use [UsbDevice](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Hardware.Usb.UsbDevice/) to communicate with the hardware peripheral if the Android-powered device is acting as the USB host. Use [UsbAccessory](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Hardware.Usb.UsbAccessory/) if the peripheral is acting as the USB host.

It's a pity that I couldn't find any official xamarin sample for USB communication, but here I found a lib and example demo which may be helpful for you:

[usb-serial-for-xamarin-android](https://github.com/ysykhmd/usb-serial-for-xamarin-android).

However it is done via Java, the same work can be done via Xamarin.Android, you can refer to [usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/blob/master/README.md), although this lib is for Java, you can follow the basic steps but use the [Xamarin USB Serial for Android lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LusoVU.XamarinUsbSerialForAndroid/0.2.3) to enable USB communication in your app.